# Передача переменной из Python на Digispark Attiny85 при помощи DigiCDC

Tags: python

Нужно производить расчеты в программе на Python, а затем передавать результат на плату Digispark Attiny85. Уже скомпилированный и загруженный скрипт на Digispark должен производить нажатие кнопки, соответствующей этой переменной.

Поискав в интернете информацию по данному вопросу, нашел, что нужно связываться из Python по СОМ-порту, к которому подключен Digispark. Однако по умолчанию СОМ-порт у платы отсутствует, плата распознается как USB устройство. На англоязычных ресурсах нашел немного информации по созданию виртуального СОМ-порта при помощи DigiCDC и запустил скрипт из примеров в Aurdino IDE:

```
        #include <DigiCDC.h>
    void setup() {                
      // initialize the digital pin as an output.
      SerialUSB.begin(); 
      /*
      remember the SerialUSB starts as soon as you call begin 
      and doesn't restart the board when you open the serial monitor 
      (like the uno does) - so if you print to it and you don't 
      have a serial monitor open that text is lost.
      */
    }

    // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
    void loop() {
      
      SerialUSB.println(F("TEST!")); //wrap your strings in F() to save ram!
      
      //SerialUSB.delay(10);
      /*
      if you don't call a SerialUSB function (write, print, read, available, etc) 
      every 10ms or less then you must throw in some SerialUSB.refresh(); 
      for the USB to keep alive - also replace your delays - ie. delay(100); 
      with SerialUSB.delays ie. SerialUSB.delay(100);
      */
    }
```

После компиляции, загрузки и последующей установки платы изначально Digispark отображается в диспетчере устройств как USB (насколько я понимаю, потому что код еще не заработал), однако через несколько секунд происходит звук отключения и последующего подключения устройства к ПК. Вот только ни в диспетчере устройств, ни в Serial Monitor не отображается новый СОМ-порт. А это, насколько я понимаю, обязательное условие, чтобы можно было связаться с Digispark из Python.

Все драйвера установлены, библиотеки и прошивка на месте, несколько раз переустанавливал. Устанавливаю плату только после компиляции и надписи "Plug in now".

Так каким же образом можно увидеть к какому порту подключилась плата после всех манипуляций и как связаться с ней из Python, чтобы передать переменную? И возможно ли это вообще?

P.S. Извиняюсь, если вопрос оказался глупым, ранее никогда не имел дела с подобными устройствами и вполне вероятно чего-то не понимаю, а информация, что мне удалось найти, достаточно скудна. Заранее благодарю всех за ответы!